# MySql table edit disabled?

Tags: mysql

I been using mysql for my project and i have been inserting some data in my table by hand using mysql workspace  and now i want to add more data next day for testing in my project i cant add it it just let me copy the text that has been added but i cant add new one. I am using latest mysql. It says it need primary key that is id but it worked without the primary key the first time i used this. Please help. Sorry for too much text i don't know how to explain correctly about this problem. If you need some more information tell me.

Comment: It is very hard to read can you try to format your test.

Comment: Umm format? my project is on visual studio 2012 as a application. I have problem mysql workspace it self not the project.

Comment: No you should format your question so that will be better readable.

Comment: Formated. I hope this is better.

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason. I did need to set the primary key for it to work i just set on random crap that will be generated by my project.